# How can I make Vista look like XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, themes

I recorded part of a video training with XP and now I have Vista installed.

I want the look of the windows (the candy buttons XP theme) to be the same through all the videos.

**How can I make Vista have that bright blue, candy-buttoned red buttons that XP has**:

[image]

When I go into Appearance Settings in vista, I only can choose from:

- Windows Aero
- Windows Vista Basic
- Windows Standard
- Windows Classic

but no Windows XP.

Comment: Why are people so attached to XP, let it go, it's a 2001 OS :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a virtual machine and install Windows XP.  Then they will look exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

[WindowsBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) by Stardock has a decent XP theme, although they didn't really try to cover up Vista in the screenshot:

[image]

The widgets can still be hidden, and explorer's style can be changed around a bit more. But the free version of WindowsBlinds will do what you want, you can see the feature comparisons [here](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/downloads.asp).

Comment: I installed the shareware version of windows blinds but under "Look & Feel" / "Visual Styles" it only has Windows Classic, Windows, Aero, Random Skin, Aero Metal, Diamond, Dragon, and Leo, how do I get Windows XP?

Comment: at wincustomize.com there are over 32 pages of XP themes, I installed "Windows XP Blue Accelerated" but the candy buttons are transparent, see through, which theme is the your screenshot above, do you have a link to it?

Comment: You can actually use the luna theme right off of XP. Although you will need SkinStudio to do the conversion, then you can use it with windowsblinds: http://www.stardock.com/products/skinstudio/

Answer (score 2):

I love some Stardock products as above, but without requiring a 3rd party program, you can go to control panel > system, then click on advanced system settings.

Click on performance button and click on "Adjust for best performance" and your pc should look rather like Windows XP when in basic / no theme mode.

Not as good as Stardock, but it works!

For the other touches, edit the start menu / task bar properties for things like no stacking e.t.c.

Comment: "How can I make vista have that bright blue, candy-buttoned red buttons that XP has" - classic is more of a dark-to-light blue bar with dull grey buttons, but it's my preferred theme on Vista or XP. I was never one for eye candy.

Comment: Well done, ignore me!